# Error: Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol with extension

Tags: ios, swift

When I try this I get error:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    ......
    }

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate { // Error: Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol 'UI
    ....
}
```

When I try this I don't get error:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        ......
        }

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate { // No error
            ...
        }
```

Why do I not add UIScrollViewDelegate to ViewController when I use extension?

If a class is type of UIViewController means it conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate ?

Comment: An extension inherits all functionality from the type it extends. Adopting a protocol twice is the same as declaring a property or method twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first code sample, you've already added conformance to `UIScrollViewDelegate` with the class declaration.

Now, when you try to conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate` again with the extension, swift screams at you.

For the second code sample the conformance is added in the extension. The class did not conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate` before the extension was added.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explaining. You don't have to conform to a protocol multiple times. 
You can either do 1)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    ......
    }
```

or

2)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
            ......
            }


extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate { // No error
            ...
        }
```

In case 1, you don't need an extension because the class itself adopts the protocol.
The purpose of the extension is to add more functionality to the class. In case 2, it is clear that the extension adopts to the protocol.